# Perform Web Data Extraction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have installed `HTMLAgilityPack`, but I cannot grasp once capturing the document table how to extract the row whose first td element contains todays date in the format `dd-mmm-yy`.

Can anybody point me in the right direction with a code snippet?

At present I have:

```cs
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://lbma.org.uk/pages/printerFriendly.cfm?thisURL=index.cfm&title=gold_fixings&page_id=53&show=2012&type=daily");
foreach(HtmlNode tr in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr"))
{
            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun. That page is horribly malformed Html, so I can see your problem. Still, I wouldn't touch XPath with a 10-foot pole. Linq makes life so much easier.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://lbma.org.uk/pages/printerFriendly.cfm?thisURL=index.cfm&title=gold_fixings&page_id=53&show=2012&type=daily");

HtmlNode todaysRow = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr").Where(n => n.InnerText.StartsWith(string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy}", DateTime.Today), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
if (todaysRow != null)
{
    List<HtmlNode> cells = todaysRow.Descendants("td").ToList();
    decimal usd = decimal.Parse(cells[1].FirstChild.InnerText);
    decimal gbp = decimal.Parse(cells[2].FirstChild.InnerText);
    // ... etc 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on XPath.  I'm still learning myself, so there may be a better path statement than this, but you need to do something like:

```
foreach(HtmlNode tr in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr[td[1] = '03-Jan-12']"))
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks... Getting the following error. Error 1 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ParentNode' and no extension method 'ParentNode' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Gravy Oops.  I was testing with SelectNode, not SelectNodes.  Does that updated code work?  I don't have HtmlAgilityPack installed, so I'm just testing with the XmlDocument object.  So I'm just assuming an HtmlNode has a ParentNode property.

Comment: Thanks for that. I now have a 2nd problem... HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://lbma.org.uk/pages/printerFriendly.cfm?thisURL=index.cfm&title=gold_fixings&page_id=53&show=2012&type=daily"); is not possible as it doesn't like to read remote urls... How can I generate an HtmlDocument from a remote URL???

Comment: @Gravy That I couldn't tell you.  I don't have any experience with that HtmlAgilityPack library.

Comment: @Gravy I actually improved the example so you don't have to loop through the td's and ask for each one parent.  That's what I was originally trying to do but couldn't get it to work initially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string key, date;
HtmlDocument doc = Load(html);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//table[@class='pricing detail']");
//this will pull out only the dates, and store them in variable 'date'
foreach(HtmlNode child in node.SelectNodes(".//tr[@class='left']")
{
    date = child.GetInnerText;
}
//this will pull out the dates and the prices, and put them into a mapped data structure for easy (and quick!) referencing
foreach(HtmlNode child in node.SelectNodes(".//tr")
{
    if(child.Attributes.contains("class"))
    {
        key = child.GetInnerText;
    }
    else
    {
        values.Add(key, child.GetInnerText);
    }
}
```

then it's just a matter of putting your text into an array or a string form your dictionary.

Explanation:
Basically, the `foreach()` bit of code will look for children only in your table matching the attribute `<tr>`. This then iterates through the collection of nodes, and does a check to see if the node is the date (i.e., if the node matches the attribute `<table class="pricing detail">`. If so, the value of this node (the GetInnerText bit), is used as a dictionary key (i.e., the date) If the comparison is false, then the code adds the subsequent child node values to the dictionary, mapped to the date key, until the date key changes.

For migrating the values from the dictionary to an output, I'm positive you can do that handily

In terms of formatting your date, see [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10825627/738448), his was very nicely done, although it looks like the dates are already formatted the way you want them to be.

I provided two foreach loops here: the first one does what you want it to do (just grabs the dates off the website). I actually wrote the second one before I fully understood what you were asking, but I'll leave it up in case you want to use it.

**NOTE**
I purposely did not make this code flexible... it's very rigidly attached to the structure of the HTML. I did this for a couple of reasons... The first is, the best way to learn how to scrape effectively is to be forced to write flexible scrapers that do not have to be fully retired after every use. I know I'm standing on a soap box, but once you really get a handle on some principles of scraping information, you'll find your programs will be much easier, smoother, and, dare I say... funner... to write and maintain. The second is, I want to encourage you to really explore the functionality that htmlagilitypack has to offer.. it really is an impressive library, and more than worth the time to play around with it.